# GTK3: Mouse vanishes when using drag and drop

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, msys2

Im trying to use the inter-widget drag-and-drop functionalities in `GTK3` with `gtkmm`. Im using Windows 7 x64 (msys2) and `gcc 5.3.0`.

When i start dragging, the mouse cursor vanishes and the DnD icon is shown at the upper left corner of the screen. Is this a bug or is there something wrong in my code?

Here you can see a very small test application with `Gtk::CheckButton` as drag source and drag destination.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>

struct DragButton : Gtk::CheckButton{
    DragButton(){
        this->signal_drag_begin().connect([](const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& ctx){
            ctx->set_icon();
        });
        this->drag_source_set({Gtk::TargetEntry("testdata")});
        this->drag_dest_set({Gtk::TargetEntry("testdata")});

        this->signal_drag_data_get().connect(
            [this](const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>&,Gtk::SelectionData& s,guint,guint ){
                std::cout << "sending data." << std::endl;
            }
        );
        this->signal_drag_data_received().connect(
            [](const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DragContext>& c,int,int,const Gtk::SelectionData&,guint,guint time){
                std::cout << "receiving data" << std::endl;
                c->drop_finish(true,time);
            }
        );
    }
};

int main(){
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("test");
    auto settings = Gtk::Settings::get_default();
    settings->set_property<Glib::ustring>("gtk-font-name","Sans 10");

    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(100,50);
    Gtk::Box box;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        box.pack_end(*Gtk::manage(new DragButton));
    }

    window.add(box);
    window.show_all();

    app->run(window);
}
```

This screenshot shows the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I found out [here](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/1906) that the `adwait-icon-theme` that is used as a default was not fully windows-compatible. The cursors `.cur` format were missing. [This](https://git.gnome.org/browse/adwaita-icon-theme/commit/?id=fa1a4b9181111c3e4d0111ee87f8b4288a1f1ecb) commit fixed the problem, I had to install the new version of the theme.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same behaviour here. Even with "official" gnome/gtk applications. For example, let's try to drag&drop widgets in Glade: you will have the same "strange" effect.

I think it's a bug of gtk libraries in Windows, but I can't imagine why this isn't solved yet, considering drag&drop is a very useful and used operation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the easiest workaround for me would be to implement my own basic DnD operations.

Comment: I found another interesting thing. Launch gtk3-demo.exe application (you can find it in msys). Run Tool Palette example. There are two DnD way: passive and interactive. Passive DnD works bad: the icon disappears during movement. Interactive DnD seems working better. Maybe you can check the source code of this example.

Comment: i found the problem and answered the quesion myself :)